# Is it worth using Fuzzy logic in stating SOC

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I am using a PIC18F controller and it handles a Battery Management system with Adc inputs..So the handling is based up on the Adc of Battery voltage and Current.I trust fuzzy can be used to determine states between High and Low.In this case How much Battery charge available is the State..and based up on that it will respond to the loads.So If the SOC is high it will use maximum load and if less minimum load.

I'm tired of using many conditional statements in the code.:) . I  have had a theoretical class on fuzzy while in college and i understand that we can judge properly the conditions b/w Full SOC and Low Soc.

Is it i'm trying unnecessary things to give high load to the system or on the right track.I just need the s/m to judge intelligently.
I will appreciate your inputs.

Thank you

Comment: Please define b/w and s/m .... it'been over 10 years since I did any fuzzy logic. If this text speak then it'not needed here in a question.

Comment: Its between and system.Its done

Comment: There is a reason you only had a _theoretical_ class on fuzzy logic and why you are having trouble finding any practical examples of its use. Bob Pease did a great series of articles about it starting in 1992: http://electronicdesign.com/digital-ics/whats-all-fuzzy-logic-stuff-anyhow